# Someone answered a question, but which one?

Tags: support, answers

I was away from stackoverflow.com for a few more hours than usual, and, when I turned up, I had a stack of notifications. One of them was that someone had answered a question of mine.

By the time I'd waded through the other notifications, that one was gone, and I'm stupidly unable to figure out how to use my user page to see what the most recent answer is to a question of mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order your questions by recent activity.  This will show edits in addition to answers, but it should be easy enough to wade through them to find the one you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: Oddly, nothing there. I must have hallucinated.

Comment: @bma - I've seen this a few times too. I assume it's because someone has deleted their answer, but the deletion was recent enough that the banner hasn't been retracted yet.